# Export large amount of data from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, export

I have to export large amount of data as JSON. So I built a query which builds the JSON-data by using Oracle-specific JSON-Functions. This seems to work fine so far. Afterwards I tried to export the data by using SQLPlus and spool the results to a file. But there seem to be 2 problems:

- Output lines are truncated after 32000 chars. I tried to change this limit by specifying different parameters, but this seems to be a hard limit. Unlimited line length is neccessary, because i don't know, how long the rows might become.
- After a few thousand rows I'm getting the following error(s):

  ```
  ERROR:
  ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numerischer oder Wertefehler: Zeichenfolgenpuffer zu klein
  ORA-06512: in Zeile 1
  ```

  It seems to be an issue with some global buffer and not with one query result. I figured this out by doing some test with different data.

Can I solve these problems or is it a bad idea in general, to export data like this? Is there a better way? I considered using `utl_file`. But if I don't misunterstand this, I would need a directory which is accessible from DBMS itself. And this I don't have...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have to use SQL\*Plus? Both SQL Developer and SQLcl have [an `sqlformat json` option](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/) that might do what you want?

Comment: I think that doesn't fit my needs, because resulting JSON needs to have specific format (hierarchical). But maybe SQLcl doesn't have the same limitations as SQLPlus and can execute my script. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It's even worse with SQLcl. It simply stops working after a few hundred lines. By the way, maybe something is wrong with my parameters:

    `SET PAGESIZE 0;
    SET NEWPAGE 0;
    SET LINES 500;
    --SET SPACE 0;
    SET ECHO OFF;
    SET FEEDBACK OFF;
    SET VERIFY OFF;
    SET HEADING OFF;
    SET MARKUP HTML OFF SPOOL OFF;
    SET COLSEP ';';
    SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    SET LINESIZE 32767;
    SET LONG 1000000000;
    SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 1000000000;
    SET TERMOUT OFF`